# How to convert this Powershell function to work within Python?

Tags: python, powershell

I have a Powershell function (which checks the % of CPU that a process uses) that I need to run WITHIN my Python code, and not just within Powershell. However, I am having trouble converting it to work there.

```
#Powershell code to convert:
$Processname = "notepad"
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter “\Process($Processname)\% Processor Time”).CounterSamples
($Samples | Select InstanceName, @{Name=”CPU”;Expression=    {[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}).CPU


#My attempt at converting it to Python:
import subprocess
processToCheck = "notepad"
process = subprocess.Popen(["powershell",
                                """Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors | $Samples = (Get-Counter “\Process(%s)\% Processor Time”).CounterSamples ; Write-Host $Samples}"""
                                % (processToCheck)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()[0]
```

When running Python version of the code, I get the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 3, in 
    % (processToCheck)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: there is no format string in the powershell that i can see in your python sub-process call. are you certain the error is in the powershell code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
processToCheck = "notepad"
script = """
    $CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
    $Samples = (Get-Counter "\Process(%s)\%% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue;
    [Decimal]::Round($Samples / $CpuCores, 2);
""" % (processToCheck)
proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell", script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.communicate()[0])
proc.wait()
```